# Does Raspberry Pi 5 work at 75hz or 100hz computer screen?

Tags: pi-5

I have a Raspberry pi 5 running raspberry OS i don't know if it can work at 100hz or 75hz screen refresh rate at 1920x1080 resolution please can anyone tell me?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a PI 5, But, based on PI 4, 1920x108 at 75/100 isn't listed. But, there are others 72,75,100 Hz modes that can fit your needs. According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/legacy_config_txt.html#hdmi-mode) you can use <hdmi_mode> Together with <hdmi_group>, <hdmi_mode> defines the HDMI output format and there are 2 tables on the link at the legacy video options HDMI mode.One for normal modes and one for overclocking modes. As PI 5 support 2x4K60fps output, thus being more powerful than PI 4 video , if you use one of the modes at the table you'll probably get a good 75 or 100 Hz refresh rate resolution.